# Graph of sin(1/x) in Metapost

Tags: metapost

How can one draw the graph of sin(1/x) in metapost, the domain being any interval near 0, say (0.0001, 2)? I tried using for loop. It does not work. Help.

```
beginfig(0)
  for i=1 upto 100:
    draw (50*2/i,50*sind(i*180/2))..(50*2/(i+1),50*sind((i+1)*180/2)); 
  endfor;
endfig;
end
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you minimum working example of what you tried

Comment: I tried only at the tip points. When i took random points the graph becomes absurd. Note that the function is not uniformly continuous near 0.

Answer (score 4):

### update

With the posted `desired picture` the original code is *not* applicable since the horizontal axis in the desired picture is probably log scale. Also, with the picture update, the OP's original logic of putting `1/x` in the first coordinate and `x` in the second coordinate also makes sense.

The modified code plot has a horizontal axis in log scale.
It also uses unequal sampling intervals (plotted in three pieces/loops)to reduce memory size (my program was crashing for large loops).

I have used
`METAPOST a user’s manual, John D. Hobby et.al version: 1.999` and `MetaPost: A Reference Manual, Peter Grogono, 22 June 2014` to find function names and loop syntax.

[image: updated sin(1/x)]

```
beginfig(0)
outputformat := "png";
% graphs like this are best plotted with unequal sample distances to reduce 
%memory usage and ensure fidelity.
for i=10 step 0.2 until 100:
draw (mlog(1/i),      50*sind(i*180/2))..
     (mlog(1/(i+0.2)),50*sind((i+0.2)*180/2)); 
endfor;

for i=1 step 0.1 until 10:
draw (mlog(1/i),      50*sind(i*180/2))..
     (mlog(1/(i+0.1)),50*sind((i+0.1)*180/2)); 
endfor;

for i=0.1 step 0.1 until 1:
draw (mlog(1/i),      50*sind(i*180/2))..
     (mlog(1/(i+0.1)),50*sind((i+0.1)*180/2)); 
endfor;
endfig;
end
```

### original answer

Disclaimer: I do not know metapost.
How ever when you plot sin(1/x) isn't it implied that the horizontal axis is `x`? But your example code has `1/i` in the coordinate for the horizontal axis. I changed it to `i`. Similarly I changed the argument of the sin to be proportional to `1/i` rather that `i`. Also `sind` takes argument in degrees. So an extraneous `180` may not be required.
I added some random constants to make the graph look nice; i.e., no aliasing. Is this how you expected the picture to look like? Since `1/x` increases very fast near zero, it is very difficult to get more cycles than shown here unless you plot in log axes or something.

[image: sin(1/x)]

```
beginfig(0)
  for i=20 upto 400:
    draw (i,    50*sind(1000000/i))..
         ((i+1),50*sind(1000000/(i+1))); 
  endfor;
endfig;
end
```

Comment: The heights of the extreme points of the graph should be the same. The graph is not as par expected.

Comment: What do you mean by extreme points? the maxima and minima; ie, the crests and troughs? If you look from the right towards the left, the extreme points are of same height for the first 4 points. Not that aliasing is difficult to avoid when plotting such a function.
When you said that it is not same, did you mean the left most points ? Can you post an example image of what you are trying to get?

Comment: Please refer to the Q again. Uploaded two pictures. First is a result of metapost code given in the question. Second picture is the expected one. Extreme points mean the troughs and crests where the values of the function are 1 and -1.